# Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Drawing.Bitmap" в "string"

Tags: c#, winforms

Обрабатываю изображения и вызываю метод RequestJson, он принимает url картинки и добавляет в dataGridView1, но RequestJson пишет Не удается неявно преобразовать тип `System.Drawing.Bitmap` в `string`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
for (int i = 0; game.games.Count > i; i++)
{
    string Url = "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/" + game.games[i].Appid + "/" + game.games[i].Img_logo_url + ".jpg".ToString();
    string bmp = RequestJson(Url);
    t.Rows.Add(new object[] { bmp, game.games[i].Name, game.games[i].Playtime_2weeks, game.games[i].Playtime_forever });
    dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
}
```

Comment: Этот метод кто написал?

Comment: Отчасти я, от части взял у кого-то

Comment: Ну смотрите, у вас в заголовке метода указан возвращаемый тип `string`, а вы пытаетесь вернуть из метода `Bitmap`, естественно это не компилируется. Как правильно - зависит от того что вы хотите получить

Comment: Я хочу получить Bitmap, изображение которое идет мне из переменной Url, в которой перебирается массив изображение. Но HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url.ToString()); должен принимать String, тогда как мне сделать тогда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все работает:

```
public Bitmap RequestJsonImage(string Url)
{
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url.ToString());
    myRequest.Method = "GET";
    HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myResponse.GetResponseStream());
    myResponse.Close();
    return bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, ты пытаешься преобразовать картинку в текст.

```
".jpg".ToString(); // часть кода.
```

Можно не делать Json запрос. А генеррирвоть сразу URL

```
var game = "730"; // APPID игр (CSGO)
```

Так же в твоем коде измени ссылку:

```
string Url = "http://cdn.edgecast.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/" + this.game +"/header.jpg
```

Comment: Нет, я пытаюсь url картинки вставить в dataGridView1. Метод RequestJson я вызываю, чтобы записать Bitmap и встать его в dataGridView1